# How to get width and height from picked image XFile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to resize and compress the image file (`XFile`) picked by [`image_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package

But I don't where to get the image information (width, height)

I tried [`image_size_getter`](https://pub.dev/packages/image_size_getter) package but I got an unsupported exception

Is there an easy way to get the width and height from `XFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 XFile? imageFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
if (imageFile != null) {
  final decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(await imageFile.readAsBytes());
final height = decodedImage.height;  // Image height
final width = decodedImage.width;  // Image width
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the below code you are able to get different things of `Image`

```
import 'dart:io';

XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(image.readAsBytesSync());
print(decodedImage.width);
print(decodedImage.height);
```